# Rearranging elements inside a superset of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dictionary in Python that comprises of multiple individual dicts:

```
raw1 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw2 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,5.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw3 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[9.8,56,56,7.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
top_dict = {
  'raw1': raw1,
  'raw2': raw2,
  'raw3': raw3
  }
print top_dict
```

I would like to flip the columns and rows in the individual dictionaries in my top_dict in such a manner that all the value fields get transposed to the Value Column and the date is appended as a row item.

As an example raw_1 in my top_dict after the flipping will look like this:

```
 raw_1 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-15','2017-03-15'],'Value':[35.6,-7.8,24,56.7,56,-31,41,56,53,41,-3.4,5],'Desc':['SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M']}
```

I know I can use pandas melt on each individual dict but how to iterate that over the entire dictionary of top_dict?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dictionary comprehension:

```
def melt_pandas(sub_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(sub_dict)
    melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Series_Date')
    return melted.sort_values('Series_Date').to_dict('list')

result = {key: melt_pandas(sub_dict)
          for key, sub_dict in top_dict.items()}
```

However, you could actually rely on numpy here which should be way faster than creating a pandas DataFrame and melting it:

```
value_cols = ['SP','1M','3M']
index_col = 'Series_Date'

def melt(sub_dict, val_cols, idx_col):
    vals = np.array([sub_dict[val_col] for val_col in val_cols]).T.flatten()
    desc = val_cols * len(sub_dict[val_cols[0]])
    date = np.repeat(sub_dict[idx_col], len(val_cols))

    return {"Series_Date": date.tolist(), 
            "Desc": desc, 
            "Value": vals.tolist()}

result_dict = {key: melt(sub_dict, value_cols, index_col)
               for key, sub_dict in top_dict.items()}
print(result)

{'raw2': {'Series_Date': ['2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15'], 
          'Value': [35.6, -7.8, 24.0, 56.7, 56.0, -31.0, 41.0, 56.0, 53.0, 41.0, 5.4, 5.0], 
          'Desc': ['SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M']}, 
 'raw3': {'Series_Date': ['2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15'], 
          'Value': [35.6, 9.8, 24.0, 56.7, 56.0, -31.0, 41.0, 56.0, 53.0, 41.0, 7.4, 5.0], 
          'Desc': ['SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M']}, 
 'raw1': {'Series_Date': ['2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-15'], 
          'Value': [35.6, -7.8, 24.0, 56.7, 56.0, -31.0, 41.0, 56.0, 53.0, 41.0, -3.4, 5.0], 
          'Desc': ['SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M', 'SP', '1M', '3M']}}
```

Timing the numpy solution yields `10000 loops, best of 3: 57.3 µs per loop` in comparison to the pandas solution `100 loops, best of 3: 6.79 ms per loop`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `Series_Date` values to be in order:

```
top_dict = {
    raw: pd.melt(
        pd.DataFrame(top_dict[raw]),
        id_vars='Series_Date']
    ).sort_values('Series_Date').to_dict('list')
    for raw in top_dict
}
```

Otherwise ommitting the `sort_values()` above would do.